# ng2-admin: How can I add pages menu items from submodule

Tags: angular

How can I add pages menu items from submodule like editors.module. I want to create module with dynamic menu items, received from the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have you tried anything? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Locate the file "pages.component.ts" and at the bottom of that file you will find a snippet of code:

`ngOnInit() {
    this._menuService.updateMenuByRoutes(<Routes>PAGES_MENU);
  }`

Do any back end calls etc. to get the data that you need and then insert the json route structure in place of PAGES_MENU.

Tested with latest version and it works great.